# Repeat Program & Changing CSS Selector

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm so new to writing Python that I'm not even sure how to search for the answer I seek, my apologies for certainly requesting information that readily exists.

I'm writing a program that pulls account numbers from an excel spreadsheet, opens the account information in a browser, scrapes information from the account page, and enters the data back into the spreadsheet. I have two issues:

I need to create a loop that pulls the next account number in the spreadsheet after the whole scraping process of the prior account is completed and I'm not sure how to do this: A2 >> A500.

My other issue is that one of the charts on the account page has unique css selectors for every account. This means, although it's all valuation information, located in the same place, same format, etc.. I can't just type ('#table-740 > tbody:nth-.....') and expect it to work. I'm using the following code:

```
oldValuation = browser.find_element_by_css_selector ('unique css selector')
```

How is this issue addressed?

My very basic code is below:

```
import bs4, requests, openpyxl
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\al\\Desktop')

addresses = openpyxl.load_workbook ('Book4.xlsx')
type (addresses)
sheet = addresses.get_sheet_by_name ('Sheet1')
cell = sheet ['E2']
```

After running the data through the scraping code I need to loop back to the above code to pull different account.. wondering if I need a for statement in there?

Thanks for your patience and your help!

Comment: Do the different CSS selectors for different accounts have anything in common? How do you know how to locate elements on the page for a specific account? Thanks.

Comment: The following bold number is the number that is unique for every account: '#table-***8339*** > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6)'                     I'm using the built in "Inspect Element" & "Copy Unique Selector" in firefox to find the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need a loop. Use the `iter_rows()` to iterate over the worksheet row by row:

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(row_offset=1):  # start with row 2
    cells = list(row)
    account_number = cells[0].value
```

Then, you can use string formatting to dynamically construct CSS selectors:

```
value_unique_for_account = cells[1]  # assuming it is in the B column
selector = "#table-%d > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6)" % value_unique_for_account

oldValuation = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
```

Comment: Fantastic advice! Thank you. I'm still having difficulty figuring out where to start the loop. Are you able to suggest any good resources for mastering this python, excel, web browser relationship?

Comment: @Ashley great, glad it worked for you. See if the answer can be accepted (the checkmark to left of the answer) to resolve this topic. As for resources, look through the most voted questions in the related topics here on SO - it is a good way to learn a new piece of technology.